# phpSPO concurrent file upload using token

Tags: file-upload

I have created a web interface to allow external users to upload files to our sharepoint library using ajax and the phpSPO library.  It all works really well, however, I am looking to optimise the upload function alot more.

Currently the all the selected files are sent together in one request to PHP then uploaded one at a time into sharepoint.

I am looking to upload multiple files concurrently.

I know how to set up the client side with ajax and the deferred/promise objects and send individual requests to the server for each file.

The bit I dont know, or even if the phpSPO library can handle it, is to Authenticate at the beginning of the process then use the token with subsequent requests to upload the files into sharepoint.

Does anyone have/know of any code snippets that show how to use the token with a phpSPO request?

EDIT:

Here is my class that initiates the connection to sharepoint:

```
class SPOInstance
{
    public $authCtx;
    public $ctx;
    public $clientfolder;
    public $log;

    function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->authCtx = new AuthenticationContext(app()->webUrl);
            $this->authCtx->acquireTokenForUser(app()->username, app()->password); //authenticate
            $this->ctx = new ClientContext(app()->webUrl, $this->authCtx);
            $token = $this->authCtx->getAccessToken();
            file_put_contents(__DIR__ .'/accesstoken.txt', $token."\r\n",  FILE_APPEND);
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'Authentication failed: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            p2($e->getTrace());

        }
    }
```

The $token variable is empty.

So once I have worked out how to get the token, how do I use that to recreate the ClientContext object for subsequent requests?

Cheers

Greg J

Answer (score 2):

If you do wish to do this purely client side using Ajax. The following snippet would assist. You simply need to get he token and create an Authorization Header of Bearer type and add the token. I forget whether the token (as returned by phpSPO ) is already Base64 Encoded. Please refer to the beforeSend Callback.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:33460/api/Account/userinfo",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  success: function(data, status) {
    return console.log("The returned data", data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + tokenString ); } //set tokenString before send
});
```

I would consider performing the subsequent request server side from phpSPO using either ClientContext or ClientRequest objects. Below is example PHP code that will establish an authenticated context.

```
$authCtx = new AuthenticationContext($Url);
$authCtx->acquireTokenForUser($UserName,$Password); //authenticate

$ctx = new ClientContext($Url,$authCtx); //initialize REST client
```

Comment: The connection to sharepoint is between the phpSPO library on the server and sharepoint.  So I would be looking at how to use the token for subsequent requests in the phpSPO library, not the client.

Comment: i see my post was a misleading with the last sentence, I have updated it

Comment: ah ok, so with both those objects, the token should persist between calls. Is that not the behavior your encountering?

Comment: i tried to get the access token but it appears to be empty.  Then even still, im not sure how to create the ClientContext object using the token.

Comment: You shouldn't have to interact with the token itself. Please see updated answer (and mark if it helps thanks)

Comment: your updated answer with the extra code is what I am using to initiate the request.  I presumed this would be the "heavy lifting" version of authenticating and also presumed that the token would enable me to re-connect with a quicker/lighter process. As its PHP, each request will be a new instance of the SPO connection object so it would seem that the same heavy lifting process to authenticate happens each time?  so i guess in my mind the initial request takes a bit of time to get the token/key then future requests can bypass the full auth because the token is pre-approval.

Comment: hmm. Are you more or less trying to store a session variable with the token in it? Are you not able to perform all of the SharePoint requests inside one PHP Page request?

Comment: I am currently performing all uploads inside one request but I was looking for a way to speed up the process by running several concurrent ajax requests which in turn would each have their own php request sending files to the server.  so in the case where there might be 5 x 50mb files being uploaded simultaneously there could be 5 separate 50mb upload requests rather than 1 request with 5 x 50mb files in it.  I dont think I can use sessions to store anything as running concurrent requests through the same session might not work very well.